# How can I run macro by first click and run another one by second click on the same button?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 2 macros one for show image and another to hide or delete this image.
I just need to show this image when I click on the button but when I click the second time hide this image again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **same** macro for **both** functions:

```
Sub ShowAndHide()
    Dim s As Shape
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1")
    s.Visible = Not s.Visible
End Sub
```

If the macro runs and the `Shape` is not visible, it will become visible.  The next time the macro runs, it will restore the `Shape` to hidden.  Repeated clicks will produce *show / hide / show / hide / show...........*

Comment: It will not work because My macros are complicated more than that. My first macro to get a photo from URL

Comment: Applying the concept, which is neatly executed in the example, is up to you, especially as you did not provide any example code originally...

Comment: @HusinAljawad  I understand your concern.  My answer is just a demonstration of technique.  You can setup two separate paths in your macro, depending on the state of visibility at entry.

Comment: Yeah, you can do an if-else block in place of the declaration, one for binding an image from url, the other to hide the image.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you want toggle between 2 macros with the same command button, the below may be used as a reference

```
Dim btnRun As Shape 'Declaring the command button variable
Sub Initializevariables()
Set btnRun = Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Button 1") 'Initiailizing the variable
End Sub
' Ensure that you have assigned Macro 1 to the command button
Sub Macro1()
Call Initializevariables
MsgBox "Macro 1 ran"
btnRun.OnAction = "Module1.Macro2"
End Sub

Sub Macro2()
Call Initializevariables
MsgBox "Macro 2 ran"
btnRun.OnAction = "Module1.Macro1"
End Sub
```